# Error in Starting the MySQL from XAMPP 3.2.1

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am using XAMPP on my windows machine for PHP and MySQL. Whenever I attempted to the start the MySQL server from the XAMPP Control Panel V3.2.1. Only Apache server is starting and MySQL stops with the following error.

```
    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
    11:41:12 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
    11:41:12 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    11:41:12 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    11:41:12 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    11:41:12 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
    11:41:12 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

Also when I checked my log. I found the following error

```
    2017-05-15 11:48:08 bc8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
    170515 11:48:08 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
    170515 11:48:08 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    170515 11:48:08 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    170515 11:48:08 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
    170515 11:48:08 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
    170515 11:48:08 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
    170515 11:48:08 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
    170515 11:48:08 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    170515 11:48:08 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    170515 11:48:08 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 12638736
    170515 11:48:08 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
    170515 11:48:08 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
    170515 11:48:08 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
    170515 11:48:08 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
    170515 11:48:08 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
    InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 12638756
    170515 11:48:09 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
    170515 11:48:09 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    170515 11:48:09 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.22-72.0 started; log sequence number 12638756
    170515 11:48:09 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    170515 11:48:09 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: some process in your system is accessing the port 3306. so you need to kill that process before starting mysql? use this command with administrator privilege in your cmd to check which process is associated with port 3306 netstat -b -p TCP

Comment: @Exprator Thanks for the response. I have also changed the port of the MySQL and also I have noticed the port 3306 is not accessed by any other application

Comment: so it is not working still?

Comment: @Exprator Yes the same error

Comment: i guess you need to uninstall and install it again to check whether it works or not

Comment: @Exprator If I reinstall the XAMPP,  Should I lose my all DB details?